# To optimize query composed subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a SQL Server database, I need to store an unknown number of columns, so I have 2 tables like this:

1. Table `Master`, with these columns: `id, data1, data2` (fixed columns)
2. Table `unknown_fields` with these columns: `id_master_record, id_field, value_field`

I do the query like this:

```
SELECT id, data1, data2, 
  (SELECT value_field FROM unknown_fields
    WHERE id_master_record = Master.id AND id_field = 1) AS data3
  (SELECT value_field FROM unknown_fields 
    WHERE id_master_record = Master.id AND id_field = 2) AS data4
  (SELECT value_field FROM unknown_fields 
    WHERE id_master_record = Master.id AND id_field = 3) AS data5
 ... SO for each 
FROM Master
```

I want to know whether there is a better way to do this query.

Comment: Do you mean `AND id_field = `, not `AND id_master_record = ` at the end of the lines?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was wrong there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this, it may be slightly faster. Best to test both. Clustering the second table on `(id_master_record, id_field)` will probably help both queries.

```
Select
  m.id,
  m.data1,
  m.data2,
  Max(Case u.id_field When 1 Then u.value_field End) As data3,
  Max(Case u.id_field When 2 Then u.value_field End) As data4,
  Max(Case u.id_field When 3 Then u.value_field End) As data5
From
  xmaster m
    Left Outer Join
  unknown_fields u
    On m.id = u.id_master_record
Group By
  m.id,
  m.data1,
  m.data2;
```

You could also try using [Pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
Select
  id,
  data1,
  data2,
  [1] as data3,
  [2] as data4,
  [3] as data5
From (
  Select
    m.id,
    m.data1,
    m.data2,
    id_field,
    value_field
  From
    Master m
      left outer join
    unknown_fields u
      On m.id = u.id_master_record
    ) as s
Pivot (
  max(value_field)
For 
    id_field In ([1], [2], [3])
) As p;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9bca/11

Comment: Thank You, I tested the three queries and I get similar times. However my query has minor cpu cost but has more nested loops, Look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9bca/10 . On my server there was no difference in performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your initial query is a fairly good way to do what you need, instead I will maybe suggest you to look into Query Execution Plan, and try to raise index on field_id, maybe this will speed up your query.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible rewrite:

```
SELECT Master.id, Master.data1, Master.data2, 
       u3.value_field AS data3,
       u4.value_field AS data4,
       u5.value_field AS data5,
       ... so for each 
FROM Master
  LEFT JOIN unknown_fields AS u3
    ON  u3.id_master_record = Master.id 
    AND u3.id_field = 1
  LEFT JOIN unknown_fields AS u4
    ON  u4.id_master_record = Master.id 
    AND u4.id_field = 2
  LEFT JOIN unknown_fields AS u5
    ON  u5.id_master_record = Master.id 
    AND u5.id_field = 3
  ... so for each  ;
```

If you want to optimize performance you should examine the execution plans for the various rewritings and make tests with your data, in your server. The indexes on the tables is vital for efficiency. The choice of the clustered index, especially for table `unknown_fields` can affect this query, too.

Two probable indexes for the `unknown_fields` are `(id_master_record, id_field, value_field)` and the (differently ordered): `(id_field, id_master_record, value_field)`